# MYSQL Table For Multi Valued Attributes Stock/Quantity

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to manage stock/quantity of products according to their attributes, for 
eg:

```
Color : Black + Size : small  = 10 Quantity
Color : White + Size : Medium = 20 Quantity
Color : White + Size : Large = 25 Quantity
```

I am just stuck on the tables, I have created the following tables but the below code can only target to 1 attribute at a time. I have a code where we can add unlimited attributes, so combining all attributes to one for the quantity.

Kindly help me with the sql tables what needs to be added or changed, to get the desired functionality.

[image]

As you can see, only 1 value of the attribute is targeted for the quantity at a time, I need to get multiple attribute values in a single record to be target for a quantity.

Answer (score 0):

You need a separate inventory table that contains 1 row for each item with its quantity.

```
id quantity
1  10
2  20
3  25
```

Then your `options_bridge` table would contain a foreign key to `inventory.id` instead of quantity:

```
id option_id value_id inventory_id
1  1         1        1
2  2         3        1
3  3         5        1
```

Those 3 rows represent

```
Size : 40 + Color : Blue + Waist : 32 = Quantity : 10
```

The point of this is that a common `inventory_id` is used to group together all the options that define a particular variation of a product. If you put the quantity in the `options_bridge` table, you have nothing linking together the rows that refer to the same item.

And when you acquire or sell an item, you only have to adjust the quantity in one place. This is more normalized.

Comment: its still the same, just replaced quantity with quantity id. A single record first from the above table represents ( size = 40 , quantity 10) , I want to get all the attributes combined in a single record to represent quantity.

Comment: The point of this is normalization. When you sell one of the items you should only have to decrement the quantity in one place.

Comment: This doesn't seem like what's needed. I'm not aware that this is a normal feature of an EAV model.

Comment: I suggest you read up on normalization. You should not duplicate a dependent value in multiple rows of a table, so if you have multiple rows with the same quantity, it's not normalized.